# Mongodb_exporter export only one mongodb metric ( --collect-all is on)

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, prometheus

I have an issue with [mongodb_exporter](https://github.com/percona/mongodb_exporter) (prometheus metrics exporter for mongodb). I think it's because of a configuration problem in my side but after 2 days of searching I'm empty of solution :)

I run mongodb on K8S and mongodb_exporter as a sidecar pod.
exporter starts OK (I think, because no error), display some metrics but my problem is that's only "go" metrics (see below), I have just one "mongodb" metric!! => mongodb_up 1. Even if i put options "--collect-all" or "--collector.collstats".
I do not have any "useful" metric on my "config" database such as collections size, etc....

Connection to the database is OK because if I change username/password/db port I ran to connection problem.
My user have correct rights I think (changing real password to "password" in my text) :

```
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "exporter",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "clusterMonitor",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "read",
                        "db" : "local"
                }
        ]
}
```

**Here is my pod configuration :**

```
        - name: metrics
          image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-exporter:latest
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - '-ec'
          args:
            - >
              /bin/mongodb_exporter --web.listen-address ":9216"
              --mongodb.uri=mongodb://exporter:password@localhost:27017/config? --log.level="debug"  --collect-all
          ports:
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 9216
              protocol: TCP
          env:
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 250Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 25m
              memory: 50Mi
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: metrics
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: metrics
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
```

**Logs**

- Exporter start log (with debug activated) :

```
time="2023-02-03T09:02:25Z" level=debug msg="Compatible mode: false"
time="2023-02-03T09:02:25Z" level=debug msg="Connection URI: mongodb://exporter:password@localhost:27017/config?"
level=info ts=2023-02-03T09:02:25.224Z caller=tls_config.go:195 msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false
```

- Displayed metrics :

```
# HELP collector_scrape_time_ms Time taken for scrape by collector
# TYPE collector_scrape_time_ms gauge
collector_scrape_time_ms{collector="general",exporter="mongodb"} 0
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the pause duration of garbage collection cycles.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 0
# HELP go_goroutines Number of goroutines that currently exist.
# TYPE go_goroutines gauge
go_goroutines 17
# HELP go_info Information about the Go environment.
# TYPE go_info gauge
go_info{version="go1.17.13"} 1
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes Number of bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_alloc_bytes 3.655088e+06
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total Total number of bytes allocated, even if freed.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total counter
go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total 3.655088e+06
[....]
# HELP mongodb_up Whether MongoDB is up.
# TYPE mongodb_up gauge
mongodb_up 1
[...]
# HELP process_virtual_memory_bytes Virtual memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_virtual_memory_bytes gauge
process_virtual_memory_bytes 7.35940608e+08
# HELP process_virtual_memory_max_bytes Maximum amount of virtual memory available in bytes.
# TYPE process_virtual_memory_max_bytes gauge
process_virtual_memory_max_bytes 1.8446744073709552e+19
```

**Environment**
K8S
MongoDB version : 4.2.0
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Maybe you shoud think of running MongoDB setup in Kubernetes using MongoDB Operator,can help definetly.

Comment: NIce example https://iamabhishek-dubey.medium.com/mongodb-setup-in-kubernetes-using-mongodb-operator-9a7be44ee70.

Comment: Thanks for responses but I don't have the possibility to use MongoDB Operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, found the solution, with the help of JMLX42 on github. The key was to take an another image. Change from `docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-exporter:latest` to `percona/mongodb_exporter:0.37.0` (and adapt the configuration) :

```
    - name: metrics
      image: percona/mongodb_exporter:0.37.0
      args:
        - '--mongodb.uri=mongodb://exporter:password@localhost:27017/config'
        - '--collect-all'
      ports:
        - name: metrics
          containerPort: 9216
          protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "50Mi"
          cpu: "25m"
        limits:
          memory: "250Mi"
          cpu: "50m"
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        initialDelaySeconds: 15
        periodSeconds: 5
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 5
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: metrics
      readinessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 3
        initialDelaySeconds: 5
        periodSeconds: 5
        successThreshold: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 1
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: metrics
```

Note : strange thing is that with `--collect-all` it does not collect collection data. I have to specify collection list  with `--mongodb.collstats-colls`.

For example : `--mongodb.collstats-colls=config.App,config.ApplicationOverride,config.Caller,config.CommonRules,config.HabilitationOverride,config.IconSvg,config.UpdateStatusEntity,config.feature`